# Dataframes in R: creating a new column which contains a value from a second column which is named in a third column

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
seq_c <- c("T", "A", "G", "T")
A <- c(0,61,135,0)
C <- c(69,125,0,0)
T <- c(133,0,0,74)
G <- c(0,134,75,0)
test <- data.frame(seq_c,A,C,T,G)
```

I want to create a new column which contains the value from column A, C, T or G depending on what the value in column `seq_c` is.

So, if the next value in column `seq_c` is a T, I want the new column to contain the value from the same row for column T. For row 1, the new column should contain '135'.

All I have so far is:

```
test <- read.table("test.txt", header = T)
test["c"] <- test$(test$seq_c)
```

My logic here is that this would fill the new column `c` with the value from the column in `test` that matches the value of `test$seq_c`. This doesn't work though.

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by indexing with the use of `match`.  `match` will find the index of each element in a vector in a second vector.  Then you can simply `sapply` over however many elements there are.

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
seq_c A C T G
T 0 61 135 0
A 69 125 0 0
G 133 0 0 74
T 0 134 75 0')

idx <- match(df$seq_c, colnames(df))
df$value <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) df[i,idx[i]])

df
  seq_c   A   C   T  G value
1     T   0  61 135  0   135
2     A  69 125   0  0    69
3     G 133   0   0 74    74
4     T   0 134  75  0    75
```

**EDIT**

An alternative suggested by @akrun you can do direct row/column indexing instead of `sapply` as well:

```
df$value <- df[-1][cbind(1:nrow(df),match(df$seq_c, colnames(df[-1])))]
```

**Benchmarking**

```
library(microbenchmark)

# bigger dataset
df <- data.frame(seq_c = sample(c("A","C","G","T"), 1000, TRUE),
                 A = sample(seq(1000), 1000),
                 C = sample(seq(1000), 1000),
                 G = sample(seq(1000), 1000),
                 T = sample(seq(1000), 1000))

fun1 <- function(df){
  idx <- match(df$seq_c, colnames(df))
  df$value <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) df[i,idx[i]])
}

fun2 <- function(df){
  df[-1][cbind(1:nrow(df),match(df$seq_c, colnames(df[-1])))]
}

fun3 <- function(df){
  ifelse(df$seq_c == "T", df$T, ifelse(df$seq_c == "A", df$A, ifelse(df$seq_c=="C", df$C, df$G)))
}

microbenchmark(fun1(df), fun2(df), fun3(df), times=10L)

Unit: microseconds
     expr       min        lq       mean    median        uq       max neval
 fun1(df) 37197.120 37669.805 39538.5973 38291.358 39667.335 46515.902    10
 fun2(df)   384.268   467.937   480.8372   495.490   513.195   553.773    10
 fun3(df)  1913.233  1934.395  1996.7215  1979.757  2068.980  2102.713    10
```

Comment: Thank you, this method works as well! Any idea which would be faster out of this and @ExpectoPatronum 's 'if else'?

Comment: @Margins, it appears that the direct indexing approach recommended by akrun wins the speed race.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ifelse, it is a very useful method.

```
df<-data.frame(seq_c=c("T", "A", "G", "T"), A=c(0, 69, 133, 0), C=c(61, 125, 0, 134), T=c(135,125,0, 75), G=c(0, 0, 74, 0))

df$new<- ifelse(df$seq_c == "T", df$T, ifelse(df$seq_c == "A", df$A, ifelse(df$seq_c=="C", df$C, df$G)))
```

df than looks like:

```
seq_c   A   C   T  G new
T   0  61 135  0 135
A  69 125 125  0  69
G 133   0   0 74  74
T   0 134  75  0  75
```